# low-graphics mode when upgraded to 18.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, upgrade, graphics

I am updating my late father's 10yr old Medion E7214 MD98360.

When 18.04 LTS was installed, it's gone into 'low-graphics' mode...

It has very basic integrated Intel graphics.

What do I do to get it working, and keep it running?

I have had a look about the forum, but as I have only basic knowledge of computers, nothing really struck me as suitable...

Also, should I upgrade further after 18.04 LTS? E.g. to 20 or 21?

Many thanks in advance for all your help

J
Aged: 55 and a half

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This is a model with I3-350 and 3GB RAM?

Comment: If 1) clean installing and 2) not 32 bit don't fuss about with 18.04 and an upgrade. Clean Install 20.04 instead.  Also, were the graphics OK when you ran the live USB?

Comment: Ubuntu has both *year.month* releases (the most common *deb* based systems) and others with a *year* format (*snap* only products*), so a change from 18.04 (*deb* based) to 20 or a completely different product is not possible as they're different products (20 is a different system to 20.04). There is no Ubuntu 21 (*year* products are even years only). Please be precise with details (*I don't see how age relates though*). Details of video card maybe helpful; eg. I use `sudo lshw -C display` in *live* mode to get some clues (`sudo` elevates privileges, *list hardware of class display*)